Why trying to pass parameters to razor components cause problem in Server Blazor?
I am trying to integrate Razor views into my ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web application.
The thing is, it works, until I pass parameters. Then, it does not throw any exception, instead the browser says

ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_RESPONSE

In Program.cs I added:
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

Also:
app.MapBlazorHub();

I also added a Components folder, and inside that _Imports.razor:
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using Nusstudios
@using Nusstudios.Components

Then, I added my custom component called CocktailView.razor:
<div class="bubble">
    <div class="space">
    @if (variants.Count() != 0)
    {
        <div class="variant">Variáns 1/@(variants.Count()+1)</div>
    }
    </div>

    <div class="title">@Cocktail.Name</div>
    <div id="header" class="row">
        <div class="left">Qty.</div>
        <div class="middle">Összetevő</div>
        <div class="right">ABV</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails.Ingredient i in Cocktail.Ingredients)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left">@(i.Quantifier.Amount.ToString() + i.Quantifier.Name)</div>
            <div class="middle">@i.Name</div>
            <div class="right">@(i.ABVPercentage.ToString() + "%")</div>
        </div>
    }
        
    <div id="stats" class="row">
        <div class="left">@(Math.Round(all, 2))cl</div>
        <div id="alc" class="middle">@(Math.Round(alc, 2))cl</div>
        <div class="right">@(Math.Round(alc / all * 100, 2))%</div>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails.Cocktail Cocktail { get; set; }
    private double all, alc;

    IReadOnlyCollection<Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails.Cocktail> variants { get; set;}

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        all = Cocktail.GetCLLength();
        alc = Cocktail.GetAlcoholCL();
        variants = Cocktail.Variants;
    }
}

After that, I created a new layout for this component called _BlankLayout.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"></link>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Edu+QLD+Beginner:wght@400..700&family=Grandstander:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&family=Indie+Flower&family=Klee+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    @RenderSection("styles", false)
    <base href="~/"/>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()        
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Then, in the Cocktails.cshtml view, I am doing the actual rendering of the component, in either of these two ways:
@using Nusstudios.Components
@using Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails;

@{
    Layout = "_BlankLayout";
    ViewBag.Title = "Koktéllap";
}

@section styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/cocktails.css">
}

@model Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails.TailData

@foreach (Cocktail c in Model.Cocktails)
{
    <component type="typeof(CocktailView)" render-mode="Server" param-Cocktail="@c" />
}

The other way is:
@using Nusstudios.Components
@using Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails;

@{
    Layout = "_BlankLayout";
    ViewBag.Title = "Koktéllap";
}

@section styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/cocktails.css">
}

@model Nusstudios.Models.Cocktails.TailData

@foreach (Cocktail c in Model.Cocktails)
{
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<CocktailView>(RenderMode.Server, new { Cocktail = c }))
}

This is my Cocktail class if it helps:
public class Cocktail
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Cocktail> Variants => variants.AsReadOnly();

    public Cocktail(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Cocktail> variants { get; set; } = new List<Cocktail>();

    public string Description { get; set; }

    private List<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Ingredient> Ingredients => ingredients.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddVariant(Cocktail c)
    {
        variants.Add(c);
    }

    public void AddIngredient(Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        int after = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.Count; i++)
            if (ingredients[i].Order < ingredient.Order)
                after = i;

        if (after == -1)
            ingredients.Insert(0, ingredient);
        else 
            ingredients.Insert(after + 1, ingredient);
    }

    public double GetCLLength() => ingredients.Aggregate(0.0, (sum, i) => i.Quantifier.ToCL() + sum);
    public double GetAlcoholCL() => ingredients.Aggregate(0.0, (sum, i) => i.Quantifier.ToCL() * i.ABV + sum);
}

However, even though seemingly I am doing it right, I am getting the browser error I described in Google Chrome. Interestingly, the view gets rendered PERFECTLY fine, when I am not trying to pass parameters to the component.
What am I doing wrong?
PS: as a side note I mention that the view which renders the razor component is available at root/Home/Cocktails, not root. I thought it might have anything to do with the base tag in the layout might foolishly assume the Blazor app is running at root, while it's not.
Although I highly doubt that would be the problem since not passing parameters does not produce this issue.
PS 2: trying to pass simple int as parameter WORKS.

You should be doing literally none of what you're doing.  Forget .cshtml.  Forget MVC.  They're gone with the dodo.  Find a tutorial series on Blazor and learn it, or read through the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@Bennyboy1973 - I would agree for a new project but what if there already is an existing website?

Is the Cocktail class (Json) serializable? I think that is a requirement.

@Bennyboy1973 I have an existent codebase in MVC but yes I am totally thinking about adapting it to Blazor completely.

@HenkHolterman How exactly could I do that? No it is not serializable I guess

Also how could I have endpoints without MVC controllers i pure Blazor app?

@HenkHolterman I've gone both ways with new projects-- try to hammer old code into the new framework, or spend time refactoring everything.  In my experience, if concerns are properly separated, then your SQL will be completely untouched, your business logic will be mostly untouched, and your UI will be a complete re-write.  It would have to be a truly MASSIVE enterprise project for me not to spend the time rebuilding the UI from scratch.
